# Update column values based on values in same column (different row) MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble changing a column value based on a value from the same column.

If the "setting_id" of `D244` has a "setting_value" of `1`, then I need to change " `8F60` to `1` as well.

Here is a sample datatable `settings`

```
| setting_id | setting_value |
| ---------- | ------------- |
|   D244     |       1       |
|   8F60     |       0       |
|   AD4F     |       1       |
```

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/083IT.png)

My attempt:

```
UPDATE settings s, (SELECT DISTINCT setting_id, setting_value FROM settings WHERE setting_value like '1' and setting_id like 'D244') s1
SET s.settingValue = s1.settingValue
WHERE s.settingID like '8F60'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
UPDATE settings s INNER JOIN settings s1
ON s1.setting_id = s.setting_id
SET s.settingValue = s1.settingValue
WHERE s.settingID like '8F60'
AND s1.setting_id = 'D244'
```